# How do I create a JUnit Test for CompareTo?

Tags: java, compareto

I am new at programming and I made a compareTo method and I want to create a test to see if it works but I don't know how to.

Comment: Same as writing a JUnit test for any other method. Read up on any basic tutorial on JUnits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first create a junit test class (it should be in the option when you right click, it's not "Class")

by default you get a method,

```
public void test(){
fail("blah blah");
}
```

test is a method name and it does not matter what it is so feel free to change it as you wish.

fail is a method from org.junit package and you don't want fail there because it will automatically fail whatever you want to test so delete it for now

now I am assuming compareTo method returns negative number or zero or positive number.

so you might want to test whether it returns a value or not first.

(http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html lists the methods you can use for testing.)

from the list, I see that assertNotNull checks for the return value by your method. if the method correctly works, it will return a value (test succeeds) but if it doesn't, it will throw exception (test fails).

```
@Test
public void test() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(yourpackage.yourclass.yourmethod(if static));

}
```

or

```
import yourpackage.yourclassname;
@Test
public void test() {
            yourclassname test = new yourclassname();
    org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(test.compareTo());

}
```

but if you have the class with the junit test class in same package, you do not need to do any import.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

All in all, you need a basic understanding of JUnit.
Below is is a simple JUnit Test, but please see [this blog post](http://cdimascio.wordpress.com/category/java/junit/) for a detailed explanation. Good luck!

```
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        // Run once before any method in this class.
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Runs once before each method annotated with @Test
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // The Sample Test case
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Test
    public void testAnotherThing() {
        // Another Sample Test case
        Me me = new Me();
        assertEquals("cmd", me.getFirstName());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Runs once after each method annotated with @Test.
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        // Run once after all test cases are run
    }

}
```